# Changing color nodes in graphDB Free

Tags: semantic-web, graphdb

I am currently working with GraphDB to visualize some data that has a graph nature. I have imported the RDF data into graphDB and actually the graph is pretty nice. The only downside is that every single node is orange.

I was wondering then, if graphDB has some mechanism whereby the color of some nodes could be changed based upon a semantic relationship between them. For example:

`<Berners_Lee> <created> <web> .
<Berners_Lee> <works_as_a> <teacher>`

If I were to load this onto graphDB all nodes would appear by default in orange. Is there any way I can specify that nodes that are pointed by relationship `created` appear in blue?

I hope everything is clear. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: IMO nodes are colored based on their type: ObjectProperties, DatatypeProperties, BlankNodes, ...

Comment: @Gilles-AntoineNys Thank you for your answer. Could it be possible to explain further? I mean how to do it in GraphDB. Regards

Comment: It is automatic. The colors are choosen arbitrary by GraphDB. I don't have changed the colors by myself yet

Comment: I am afraid that is not happening in my case. I am loading my RDF file (the one full of triples) and then visualizing the graph and all nodes are orange. In your case how are you importing the data into graphDB? Have you specified some sort of configuration? Thank you in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are generated automatically and differentiate the types in one graph, which is their main purpose. Also we do not handle properly the case with multiple types for a node, but we have it in mind. The problem with your data is that all of the subject predicates and objects have no type (which makes them the same type). Here is a small example, based on your data which will produce the desired effect.

```
<Berners_Lee><created><www>;
             <works_as_a><teacher>;
             a <Person>.
<teacher> a <Occupation>.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your contribution. Best wishes. @Konstantin Petrov